# Cloud-init: Add apt source key gnupg not installed

Tags: apt, cloud-init

I've a cloud-init script that is used to create and configure a Debian 10 VM and since I want to install nginx I have to add its repository to APT.  I'm trying to do it like this:

```
apt:
  preserve_sources_list: true
  sources:
    nginx:
      source: "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian $DEBIAN_RELEASE nginx"
      key: |
          -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
          Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)

          mQENBE5OMmIBCAD+FPYKGriGGf7NqwKfWC83cBV01gabgVWQmZbMcFzeW+hMsgxH
          QxnZZIbETgcSwFtDun0XiqPwPZgyuXVm9PAbLZRbfBzm8wR/3SWygqZBBLdQk5TE
          ...
          =EWWI
          -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
packages:
  - nginx
```

It doesn't work and cloud-init's log file at `/run/cloud-init/result.json` shows the following:

```
{
 "v1": {
  "datasource": "DataSourceConfigDrive [net,ver=2][source=/dev/vdb]",
  "errors": [
   "('apt-configure', ProcessExecutionError(\"Unexpected error while running command.\\nCommand: ['apt-key', 'add', '-']\\nExit code: 255\\nReason: -\\nStdout: \\nStderr: E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation\"))"
  ]
 }
}
```

Why? It complaints it can't use `apt-key` because `gnupg` isn't present however how can I make sure it exists? According to `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` cloud-init runs the APT modules before installing packages so how am I supposed to get a working `apt-key` with `gnupg`?

Thank you.

Comment: What method are you using to install debian? That is where you would specify to install gpg or select an "image" that has gpg installed.

Comment: @MarkWagner I'm using a Debian 10 image from DigitalOcean. I guess it is bare bones basic Debian. Is there a way to do it in the cloudinit stage?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your configuration, which causes apt-get to run after the network is up but before the official cloud-init sections:

```
bootcmd:
  - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq update
  - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install gnupg
```

There's another solution on the [Debian Bug Tracking System](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=970796#40) which shows you how to specify a new source and key without causing a call to gnupg, but (for me) that makes your cloud-init configuration less clear.